# SensorTag20 error scanning services

Tags: android, tags, sensors, texas-instruments

I was trying to run [SensorTag-20-Android app](https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android) but when I try to connect to the sensor the app doesn't go ahead. It remains blocked on "Generating Gui - Found a totoal fo 14 service with a total of 41 charateristics.....".
After Trying debugging the code, i found that scanning the services list (at the top) it returns on the service with *UUID 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb*
the Log message is "D/DeviceActivity: No characteristics found for this service!!"

Any suggestions?
Thanks, Federico.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I can get it running when I comment out the return behind the the log message. Search for the log message in the DeviceActivity.java:

```
if (chars.size() == 0) 
{ 
    Log.d("DeviceActivity", "No characteristics found for this service !!!");
     //return;
 }
```